# PostgreSQL client version in QGIS

Tags: postgresql

How can I determine which version of libpq that my distro of QGIS is running? When I open the 'about' section, it says 'unknown'. I started looking through some source and doc, and seems like the PostgreSQL Client comes via GDAL. Ultimately, I am trying to get QGIS to connect to a PostgreSQL server that requires Server Name Indication, which I think came in PostgreSQL 14?

[image]

Next step I will likely try compiling from source so that I can perhaps specify the version of libpq used in GDAL.

I'm running QGIS in MacOS and got the .dmg here https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Answer (score 5):

If you use the OSGeo4W installer you may check (and install or remove) library and see witch version is installed.

In my QGIS 3.34.1 installation libpq is version 15.2-1

[image]

Comment: I'm running on MacOS (updated my question with that detail). Is there a tool like this available on Mac?

Comment: @Adam I'm not familiar with MacOS, hope someone could provide more information